# $r''-r(\theta')^2=f(r)$ what is wrong during the steps

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was in the process of proving. Given is the LHS in the first line $$r''-r(\theta')^2=f(r)$$  and I want to get the RHS, using the given substitution in the second line. I am not quiet sure about the process. After my own proof, what I get is the last line - there is an additional negative sign in the first term. [image: Could you plz give some suggestion thank you!!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post more context, then the task becomes more comprehensible. You start from the gravity equation for the one-body system
$$
\ddot z = -\frac{\mu z}{|z|^3}
$$
which in polar coordinates $z=re^{i\theta}$ gives the constant angular momentum $r^2\dot \theta=h=const.$ and the radius equation
$$
\ddot r-r\dot \theta^2=f(r)=-\frac{\mu}{r^2}
$$

---

What follows afterwards is just wrong in the middle part, or very badly written. As $r$ is not a function of $u$, there need to be inner derivatives in the derivarives of $r=1/u$. Or it needs to be clearly indicated that $\frac{dr}{du}$ and $\frac{d^2r}{du^2}$ are computed, along with what derivative the primes indicate, that is, what the free variable in every formula is.

Declaring the composition that is used clearly by setting $$r(t)=\frac{1}{u(θ(t))}$$ gives a much more straight-forward derivation of the result, note that $u\ne 0$ always.
\begin{align}
\dot r(t) &= -\frac{u'(θ(t))\dot θ(t)}{u(θ(t))^2}
%\\&
=-u'(θ(t))\,\dot θ(t)r(t)^2
%\\&
=-h\,u'(θ(t)) \\
\\
\ddot r(t) &=- h\,u''(θ(t))\dot θ(t)=-h^2\,u''(θ(t))u(θ(t))^2
\end{align}

Now insert into the radius equation to get
$$
-h^2\,u''(θ(t))u(θ(t))^2-h^2\,u(θ(t))^3=-\mu u(θ(t))^2
\\~\\
\implies u''(θ)+u(θ)=\frac{\mu}{h^2}
$$